# How to overload generic IEnumerable

Tags: c#, generics, ienumerable

I understand this is a common problem to try to overload a single generic and array generic. All of those answers talk about why it works this way and how there are better ways to do, but none of them show it. I am looking for suggestions on how to accomplish what I am after and I am open to refactors and doing it a different way

Here is the code that represents the issue:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/sWrNj3

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

public static class MyParser
{
    public static void Parse<T>(string name, T value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{name}: single");
    }

    // Must take in IEnumerable<T>
    public static void Parse<T>(string name, IEnumerable<T> collection)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{name}: IEnumerable");
    }

    public static void ParseObj<T>(T data)
    {
        foreach (var prop in data.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public))
        {
            Parse(prop.Name, prop.GetValue(data, null));
        }
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        MyParser.ParseObj(new
        {
            Str = "abc", 
            Num = 543, 
            Arr = new[]{1, 2, 3}, 
            Chars = new char[]{'x', 'y', 'z'}}
        );
    }
}
```

Outcome:

```
Str: single
Num: single
Arr: single
Chars: single
```

Desired:

```
Str: single
Num: single
Arr: IEnumerable
Chars: IEnumerable
```

Comment: The problem is that `GetValue()` returns an `object`, so the compiler will always bind to the method that takes an `object`. If you want to have this kind of differentiation, you need to decide at runtime (e.g. `if(value is IEnumerable<...>`).

Comment: *I understand this is a common problem.* I don't agree this is a common problem; indeed, I would characterize this as an abuse of generics. Why exactly are you trying to do this?

Comment: The common mistake is thinking you should make your class generic first then specialize it after you figure out what you will be using it for. This rarely works, and is an enormous amount of effort even if it did work. First figure out one type your class must support and write your class specifically for that type. If it later turns out you need your class for a different type, then is the time to start considering extending it. Stop wasting your time trying to build a do-everything-car-boat-airplane-snowmobile-pogo-stick until after you know how you need to travel.

Comment: In addition to all the good advice above, I will also point out that overload resolution isn't going to work the way you want anyway. You have to case an array to `IEnumerable<T>` for the compiler to choose that generic method overload, but of course that's not the runtime type of the object. So any solution that is based on the actual runtime type of the object will fail. You need to explicitly check at runtime for enumerables, if that's the distinction you want to make.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have all the information you need right there, but you cannot delegate all that work to the compiler, you have to do the work yourself:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using static System.Console;

public static class MyParser
{
    public static void ParseObj<T>(T data)
    {
        foreach (var prop in data.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public))
        {
            if(prop.PropertyType.IsArray) WriteLine($"{prop.Name}:array");
            else if(prop.PropertyType == (typeof(string))) WriteLine($"{prop.Name}:string");
            else if(prop.PropertyType.IsValueType) WriteLine($"{prop.Name}:value type");
            else if(typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(prop.PropertyType)) WriteLine($"{prop.Name}:IEnumerable");
            else if(prop.PropertyType.IsEnum) WriteLine($"{prop.Name}:enum");
            else if(prop.PropertyType.IsClass) WriteLine($"{prop.Name}:class");
            else WriteLine($"{prop.Name}:something else");
        }
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        MyParser.ParseObj(new
        {
            Str = "abc"
            , Num = 543
            , Arr = new[]{1, 2, 3}
            , Chars = new char[]{'x', 'y', 'z'}
            , SomeList = new List<string>(){"a","b","c"}
        });
    }
}
```

output:

```
Str:string
Num:value type
Arr:array
Chars:array
SomeList:IEnumerable
```

*** UPDATE ***
Adding the evolution of the code to the answer from the comments in case anyone else finds this question useful:

1. https://dotnetfiddle.net/Zkx7UJ
2. https://dotnetfiddle.net/aeCG3z
3. https://dotnetfiddle.net/6Z49ta
4. https://dotnetfiddle.net/u5HAFP

Comment: I think this is acceptable but I still can't get it to infer it is an IEnumerable https://dotnetfiddle.net/aeCG3z

Comment: Yeah unforunately this is where the proof of concept breaks down. I have to take in an IEnumerable<T>  on the ParseCollection because inside ParseCollection I am sending a thirdparty thing a `IEnumerable<T> ` so that's why I need it

Isn't there a way to cast to IEnumerable because it's already IEnumerable, but I dont think its possible to cast it to whatever it's underlying type is

Comment: You can still do it, but things start to get much more complicated: https://dotnetfiddle.net/u5HAFP

Comment: Thanks, was able to get this to fit my needs